# Does singleton means hashcode always return the same?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have two objects, o1 and o2 from the same class.

If `o1.hashcode() == o2.hashcode()`, can I tell they are the same object?

Beside `o1==o2`, is there any other way to tell the singleton.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a single instance of the class, the `==` and the `equals` comparison will always return `true`.

However, the `hashcode` can be equal for different objects, so an equality is not guaranteed just by having equal hashcodes.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) is a nice explanation of the `hashcode` and `equals` contracts.

Checking the equality is not sufficient to be sure that you have a singleton, only that the instances are considered equal.

If you want to have a single instance of a java class, it may be better to make use of static members and methods.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java), several approaches to singletons are demonstrated.

EDIT: as emory pointed out - you could in fact override `equals` to return something random and thus violate the required reflexivity (`x.equals(x) == true`). As you cannot override operators in java, `==`  is the only reliable way to determine identical objects.

Comment: If you have a single instance of the class the == comparison will always return `true`.  If you have a single instance of the class and at least a half-assed implementation, the `equals` comparison will always return true, but the `equals` comparison need not always return true if the implementation is wicked.

Comment: @emory - you're right. `==` is the only reliable source here. Thanks for pointing out, I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

No, different objects can have the same `hashCode()`:

```
"hypoplankton".hashCode()
"unheavenly"  .hashCode()
```

both return the same `427589249` hash value, while they are clearly not equal.

Answer (score 2):

Your question (from the title) seems to be "will `hashCode()` always return the same value for the same object"... the answer is **no**.

The implementation is free to return anything, although to be well behaved it *should* return the same for the same object. For example, this is a valid, albeit poor, implementation:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general contract for the **hashCode** is described below (*Effective Java, page. 92*). The 3rd item means that the hashCode() results do not need to be unique when called on unequal objects.

1. Within the same program, the result of hashCode() must not change
2. If equals() returns true when called with two objects, calling hashCode() on each of those objects must return the same result
3. If equals() returns false when called with two objects, calling hashCode() on each of those objects does not have to return a different result